# PHP IF/Type Issue

Tags: php, if-statement

Trying to get some clarification on this. Have a test form where you submit a letter and it gives a corresponding message.

```
if ($letter = "A") { $message = "First letter."; }
if ($letter = "B") { $message = "Second letter."; }
if ($letter = "C") { $message = "Third letter."; }
```

It keeps giving the last $message possible, in this case "Third letter." I know it has something to do with the operator/conditional statement and = sign, just not sure what to use properly. Thanks!

Comment: if you want these true then it should be `if ($letter == "A")` use `==`

Answer (score 3):

`==` called PHP Comparison Operators

With `==` means `$x == $y`, it Returns true if $x and $y have the same key/value pairs

`=` called PHP Assignment Operator

and `=` means `$x = $y` The left operand gets set to the value of the expression on the right

[More Detail here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp)

Answer (score 2):

`=` is the assignment operator, so you’re bascially asking “Did it work to assign ‘A’ to $letter?”. This will be always true.

The comparison operator is `==`, so it should be `if ($letter == "A") ...` and so on.

Comment: The `=` operator actually *returns* the value it set.  `if ($letter = "A")` is the same as doing `$letter = "A"; if ($letter)`.  It may not always be true, like what if you did `if($test = false)`?

Comment: I was only referring to the `$letter = "A"` example, otherwise you’re right. :)

Answer (score 2):

`=` sets `$letter` to the value, and because that setting worked, it returned `true` each time, so actually `$message` was being set every time, but only the last one remains.

Use `==` for comparison. Or better yet, have a data structure for the answer, then pull it from there:

```
$answers = array(
    'A' => 'First letter.',
    'B' => 'Second letter.',
    'C' => 'Third letter.'
);
$message = array_key_exists($letter, $answers) ? $answers[$letter] : '';
```

Comment: The `=` operator actually *returns* the value it set.  `if ($letter = "A")` is the same as doing `$letter = "A"; if ($letter)`.  It may not always be true, like what if you did `if($test = false)`?